# Questions regarding Holder's and Minkowski's inequality

Tags: normed-spaces

I've some questions regarding *Holder's and Minkowski's inequality* as given in my [text](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Topology_of_Metric_Spaces.html?id=ehZ_LRmG3JMC&redir_esc=y):

[image]
[image]

- **Does the author consider the case $q=\infty$ in the equality case of lemma 1.1.36?**
- **Shouldn't the author mention $C_1,C_2$ are not all zero in the equality case of lemma 1.1.37?**

  **I think telling the 'iff' condition for equality as the linear independence of $a,b$ would be better.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author's statement cannot make sense for infinity in the first example, as raising to the inifitieth power doesn't make sense. However, it is not hard to see for positive values that equality can only hold if $b_i$ is constant.

The answer to the second question is, of course, 'yes'.

Actually, if you take the equality statement and take the $q$th root of both sides and take the limit, you get that $b_i$ must be constant.

Comment: The author has explicitly defined $\|x\|_{\infty}$ in the statement of the lemma. You do not take the $\infty$th power.

Comment: The OP is asking about the *equality* statement, not the inequality statement.